# Prestashop add to cart button doesn't work

Tags: prestashop

I have disabled price displays for visitors on my shop. So, they have to log in/register to see the prices.

To checkout, they have to register/log in too. Guess checkout being disabled.

However, I want to allow them to add the products to their cart even if they are not logged in and don't see the prices. They will only need to log in if they want to purchase/checkout.

If i enable price displays for visitors on my site, everything works fine. However, when I disable it, the add to cart button no longer works.

Suggestions on making it work for visitors too?

Answer (score 0):

In `prestashop/themes/yourtheme`:

Edit `product-list.tpl` and `products.tpl` by adjusting the Smarty {if} statements surrounding the 'Add to cart' button/link so that the link shows even when prices are disabled.

Edit `shopping-cart.tpl` and `shopping-cart-product-line.tpl` by adding Smarty {if} statements to hide prices when users are not logged in.

There might be a few other places to edit, but that should get you started.